# Live app updates using real time database listener or firestore Realtime data?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

I created this custom hook that will listen for changes when I deploy a new version of my app to enable force updating the app. In my app, I have some implementations that use Fire-store real-time data, and I am sure I won't be changing that. But what is really the difference between a real-time database and Cloud Fire-store Realtime data regarding battery life? I don't want this live update implementation to drain users' batteries, or if both together could throw a wrench into my overall implementation

```js
// Firebase
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { realTime } from '../../../firebase/firebase';
import { ref, onValue } from 'firebase/database';
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from '../../../redux-store/hooks';
import { setAppVersion } from '../../../redux-store/authSlice';

const useAppVersion = () => {
  // Redux
  const appVersion = useAppSelector((state) => state.auth.appVersion);
  // Dispatch
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const [localAppVersion, setLocalAppVersion] = useState<null | string>(null);

  // Get the current app version.. set it to the state and listen for changes
  const listenAppVersionChange = () => {
    const starCountRef = ref(realTime, 'appVersion');
    onValue(starCountRef, (snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.val();
      console.log('appVersion', data);
      // Set the app version in redux
      dispatch(setAppVersion(data));
    });
  };
  // Track the app version
  useEffect(() => {
    setLocalAppVersion(appVersion);
    if (appVersion && localAppVersion) {
      if (appVersion !== localAppVersion) {
        alert('New version is available.');
      }
      return;
    }
  }, [appVersion]);

  return { listenAppVersionChange };
};

export default useAppVersion;
```

Answer (score 1):

> But what is really the difference between a real-time database and Cloud Fire-store Realtime data regarding battery life?

They both use a websocket on the client to receive updates to the data as it changes.  If it's the same rate of data change, there is no appreciable difference in power usage between the two.  Neither of them are "spinning" to check for new data as long as that websocket is able to be maintained so the data can be pushed.

If you are deeply concerned about usage, you should perform your own benchmarks, because we can't really predict how your app is going to behave under actual production usage scenarios.

Comment: While you're correct about neither of them spinning, only Realtime Databas uses web sockets. Firestore does *not* use web sockets for its synchronization protocol, but uses web channel over regular HTTP.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen so is there any difference regarding stress on battery ?

Comment: It's the same effect - they are just waiting for new data and doing nothing in the meantime. That "nothing" costs no additional battery than what's already being used by other things.